# Tag Helpers Cache expires-on fails Unexpectedly

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Using the latest .net Core Razor Tag Helpers, I have the following usages of expires-after and expires-on in my index.cshtml file.

When I refresh the page every second, the first line (expires-after) only changes every 5 seconds as I expect.

When I refresh the page every second, the second line (expires-on) changes every second. I would expect both lines to behave the same.

```
expires after (working): <Cache expires-after="@TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)">
  @DateTime.Now</Cache>

expires on (not working) <Cache expires-on="@DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5)">
  @DateTime.Now</Cache>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting a new value for "expires-on" each time the page is rendered. 
It seems like the MVC framework's caching mechanism refreshes the cache each time a different value "expires-on" is set.
A small tweak of your example, as follows, gives the behaviour you were expecting:

```
<Cache expires-on="@(new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year,DateTime.Now.Month,DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, (int)(DateTime.Now.Second/10) * 10)).AddSeconds(10)">
  @DateTime.Now</Cache>
```

(This is for a c# Razor template.) 
This tweak works because the new expression for "expires-on" provides a value that stays constant except for a new value every 10 seconds. Here's the same expression in a more legible layout:

```
(new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year,
  DateTime.Now.Month,
  DateTime.Now.Day, 
  DateTime.Now.Hour, 
  DateTime.Now.Minute, 
  (int)(DateTime.Now.Second/10) * 10))
.AddSeconds(10)
```